React Native: Problema con notificaciones push en segundo plano
Estoy teniendo un inconveniente con mi app en Android cuando recibe notificaciones push en background. La app está construida con React Native y estoy usando @react-native-firebase/messaging para manejar las notificaciones de FCM. El entry point de mi app (index.js) tiene el siguiente código:
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';


messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
    console.log('Background Handler: ', remoteMessage);
});

function HeadlessCheck({ isHeadless, notificationWithLink }) {
    if (isHeadless) {
        return null;
    }

    return <App notificationWithLink={notificationWithLink} />;
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => HeadlessCheck);

Cuando una notificación push llega con la app cerrada, setBackgroundMessageHandler se ejecuta y puedo ver en consola el contenido de remoteMessage. Ahora cuando la app está en segundo plano, este handler NO se ejecuta.
En ambos casos, la notificación es desplegada por el sistema, pero necesito manejar el evento de llegada de la notificación con la app en segundo plano  para enviar información a analytics.
El body de la request que hago a FCM es:
{                  
   "message":  {        
        "android":{
            "priority":"high"
        },
        "apns":{
            "headers":{
                "apns-priority":"5"
            }
        },
        "token": "BSDJAJSDASNLDKAKLSDLKVDNFODSKFOPKSDFSFIOJIOEOIGJEOIRGJIOSDOIFJIADSOJFOIA",        
        "notification": {
            "title": "Notification title",
            "body": "Notification description"
        },
        "data": {            
            "phone_number": "1234567890",
            "deep_link": "myDeeplink"
        }
   } 
} 

No tengo en claro cual podría ser el problema.
